# Converting Key Text To Key Character

Tags: java, keylogger

I have a global keylogger which prints out the pressed key on the console. You can find the code [here](http://www.javaquery.com/2014/05/how-to-create-key-logger-in-java.html).

When I press a regular key letter or number it'll print the key character but the "special" keys like `ENTER`, `SPACE` and so on print their names instead of the key character.

I for example get `ENTER` but I really wanted a new line character like `\n` or `System.lineSeparator()`. Instead of checking and converting everything manually, is there a way to get all of the proper key characters to write a log similar to how a text editor would produce its result?

I tried using `getKeyChar()` from the `NativeKeyEvent` class but it only displays a `?`.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to write your own converter taken from the source code of `jnativehook`. Looking at the code from the link you provided, there is a call to

`NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(int keyCode);`.

So in my opinion the easiest way would be to write something similar or reuse that code, changing the values of keys such as `VC_SPACE` to return what you want. I don't believe there is anything which works quite the way you want it to so this would be a good compromise.

Note: in your implementation be careful what to return for key codes such as `VC_ENTER` which might be platform-specific, but it depends on your needs really - I wouldn't worry too much about it if all you want is a simple keylogger.

Answer (score -1):

So you want the normal keys printed like this: a,b,c,4 and the special like space: , enter like \n ...

you can do `NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()).replace("enter","\n");` but you don't want... 
There is no other posibillity...

Comment: The method `getText()` is undefined for the type `String`.